# Why do certain python programming environments facilitate printouts of a variable's value differently?

Tags: python, variables, io, ide, ipython

For python programming, in most IDE's, the programmer must write the following in order to see a_var's value displayed in output:

```
print(a_var)
```

Contrarily, when using python in the Unix/Linux terminal, or in an Jupyter Notebook, simply writing:

```
a_var
```

on a line will cause this variables value to display in output.

How and why does this differ intrinsically between different programming or development environments?

Answer (score 1):

Python running interactively, or via a Ipython/Jupyter session is using a REPL, Read–Eval–Print Loop.  This code reads your input, evaluates it, and prints the result.  Each REPL will have its own rules for suppressing or allowing the display.  It may display the `str` or `repr` version.  It may also save the result in a temporary variable (often called `_`).

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you're using your IDE to write a program for Python to read in the whole thing and then execute, but in the second case you're just typing directly into the Python interpreter/shell.

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html